A inequality involving an exponential non linearity of a PDE
Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ a continuous function and suppose there exists $\alpha_0 > 0$ such that
$$
\lim_{|s| \to +\infty} \frac{|f(s)|}{e^{\alpha |s|^{N/(N-1)}}} = 0, \quad \forall \alpha > \alpha_0
$$
and
$$
\lim_{s \to 0} \frac{f(s)}{|s|^{N-1}} = 0.
$$
Define
$$
\Phi_\alpha(s) = e^{\alpha |s|^{N/(N-1)}} - \sum_{j=0}^{N-2} \frac{(\alpha |s|^{N/(N-1)})^j}{j!}.
$$
How to show that for a given $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $C > 0$ such that
$$
|f(s)| \leq \epsilon |s|^{N-1} + C |s|^{q - 1} \Phi_\alpha(s),
$$
for any $q \geq 1$ and $\alpha > \alpha_0$ ?
My attempt: I know for a given $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta_1 > 0$ such that
$$
|f(s)| \leq \epsilon |s|^{N-1}, \quad \forall |s| < \delta_1.
$$
Also, given $A > 0$, there exists $\delta_2 > \delta_1 $ such that
$$
|f(s)| \leq A e^{\alpha |s|^{N/(N-1)}} , \quad \forall |s| > \delta_2.
$$
I know how to conclude that there exists $C > 0$ such that
$$
|f(s)| \leq C e^{\alpha |s|^{N/(N-1)}} , \quad \forall |s| \geq \delta_1.
$$
At this point I don't know what to do.
